# Print zero for blank/empty result in oarcle sql query

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I want to display 0 when query returns no records . I tried with nvl but its not working . please advise .

```
create table  temp (id number , cat varchar2(10));
insert into temp values (100,'EUR');
insert into temp values (101,'MAR');
insert into temp values (102,'AST');
insert into temp values (103,'GHK');
insert into temp values (104,'MST');
insert into temp values (105,'LAL');


select TOTAL_CNT , COUNT(*) 
FROM
(
SELECT 'T' TOTAL_CNT, nvl(count(DISTINCT id),0) cnt FROM TEMP GROUP BY CAT
union all
SELECT  'U' UNIQUE_CNT ,nvl(count(DISTINCT id),0) cnt FROM TEMP GROUP BY CAT HAVING  COUNT(DISTINCT ID)>1
) GROUP BY TOTAL_CNT;
```

expected output : I am not getting "U" values.

```
TOTAL_CNT    COUNT(*) 
       T          6
       U          0
```

Comment: There is nothing which would be matching as a U value; All IDs appear exactly once only.

Comment: Thanks @TimBiegeleisen for quick response .  If there is no unique ids I want to print 0 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one option:

```
SQL> with
  2  t_unique as
  3    (select count(distinct id) cnt
  4     from temp
  5     group by cat
  6     having count(distinct id) > 1
  7    ),
  8  t_total as
  9    (select count(distinct id) cnt
 10     from temp
 11     group by cat
 12    )
 13  select 'T' what, (select count(*) from t_total ) cnt from dual
 14  union
 15  select 'U' what, (select count(*) from t_unique) cnt from dual;

WHAT         CNT
----- ----------
T              6
U              0

SQL>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want the values as columns (not rows) then you only need to `SELECT` from the table once and aggregate twice (using conditional aggregation to find the `U` values):

```sql
SELECT COUNT(COUNT(DISTINCT id)) AS t,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT id) > 1 THEN 1 END) AS u
FROM   TEMP
GROUP BY CAT;
```

Which outputs:

| T | U |
| --- | --- |
| 6 | 0 |

If you do want it as rows then you can `UNPIVOT` (which, again, does not use `UNION` and only `SELECT`s from the table once):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT COUNT(COUNT(DISTINCT id)) AS t,
         COUNT(CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT id) > 1 THEN 1 END) AS u
  FROM   TEMP
  GROUP BY CAT
)
UNPIVOT (cnt FOR total_cnt IN (t, u));
```

Which outputs:

| TOTAL_CNT | CNT |
| --- | --- |
| T | 6 |
| U | 0 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/qHTRRmz0)